# How I can make IntelliJ understand that Hibernate listeners are autowired?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

I have a Hibernate entity which has a listener attached using the `@EntityListeners` annotation

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(value = UpdateListener.class)
public class User
{
    //fields
}
```

This listener looks like this

```
@Slf4j
public class UpdateListener {
    private final TestDep testDep;

    public UpdateListener(TestDep testDep) {
        this.testDep = testDep;
    }

    @PrePersist
    void preCreate(User taxonomy) {
        log.info("pre create");
    }

    @PostUpdate
    void postUpdate(User taxonomy) {
        log.info("post update");
    }
}
```

I thought this might be a problem since there isn't a no-argument constructor but, to my surprise, Spring actually has no problem with it and will autowire the constructor just as it would for a bean. `TestDep` just looks like this, by the way

```
@Component
public class TestDep {}
```

The problem I have that IntelliJ does not understand that this constructor is autowired, so it does not give any suggestions about where the dependency comes from. Usually there's a green circle with a slash through it when it's able to infer the relationship.

[image: Green spring bean circle]

I tried marking the constructor as `@Autowired` but it doesn't help IntelliJ to understand what's going on, and in fact sparks a warning (which makes sense)

```
@Autowired // WARNING: Autowired members must be defined in valid Spring bean (@Component|@Service|...)
public UpdateListener(TestDep testDep) {
    this.testDep = testDep;
}
```

If I make the listener a `@Component`, I get the dependency hints but Spring instantiates it twice, once via `@Component` and once via `@EntityListeners`.

Is there another way I can approach this?

Comment: Just suppress the warning and move on...

Comment: @AlanSereb You misunderstand. By adding `@Autowired`, I still do not get the desirable behaviour. So suppressing the warning doesn't help me - I may as well just remove `@Autowired`. Updated my question to hopefully make this more clear

Comment: Would be great if you file an issue with a minimal sample at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA